# Bash Scripting how to put a string into a variable?

Tags: macos, bash

Hello I want to put a string into a variable and I am having problems...
Here is what I am trying to do, I want to compare to variables and this is what I have so far

```
#! /bin/bash
Output=$(sudo systemsetup -getnetworktimeserver)
Variable="Time Server: abc.dd.jj.com"
if [ "$Output" = "$Variable" ]
 then
   echo "OK"
  else
   echo "FALSE"
 fi
```

Now the $Output variable gets the right string however the $Variable does not it just gives me an error saying that "line 3: Server :: command not found"
How do I get that string into the $Variable variable so I can compare the two?

Comment: Is that your actual script? Because that should work. Do you perhaps have `Variable="$(Time Server: abc.dd.jj.com)"` instead?

Comment: Yeah that my actual script

Comment: Can you double check please because that just can't be the case. That script above works. (I don't have OS X so I replaced that command with an echo but that shouldn't change anything). Can you show us the output of that systemsetup call by itself? Do you perhaps have `Variable=Time Server: abc.dd.jj.com`? Or are those quotes some sort of "smart quotes"?

Comment: True, i just tested, it works for me..

Comment: Most likely, there are no double-quotes around `$VARIABLE` in his `if` statement when he runs it.  Or, what Etan says.  :)

Comment: This works for me also on OSX, although the string that is returned from the `systemsetup` command is `Network Time Server` not just `Time Server`

Comment: If MS Windows was involved in creating, editing or ftping(etc) your file, then "clean" it up with `dos2unix myScript.sh`. Good luck.

Comment: Is is possible the quotes in `Variable="Time Server: abc.dd.jj.com"` aren't plain ASCII quotes, but some sort of fancy typographer's (or "smart") quotes? 'Cause the shell doesn't recognize anything but plain quotes.

Comment: Etan was right, it was smart quotes! Im sorry I didnt think of that before, thank you for the help guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Etan was right, it was smart quotes that was enabled! Im sorry I didnt think of that before, thank you for the help guys!